# Find NON-ZERO matrices $A,B,C,D \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find NON-ZERO matrices $A,B,C,D \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2$.

Of course nilpotent matrices will work. But can we find non-nilpotent matrices as examples.

Comment: Vaserstein and Granville have solved this (I will look up the link). Do you require that *all* matrices are non-nilpotent?

Comment: ok.............

Comment: yes, I need all matrices are non nilpotent.

Comment: It's easy if you only want to find *one* example. E.g. $$\pmatrix{3\\ &0}^2+\pmatrix{4\\ &4}^2+\pmatrix{0\\ &3}^2=\pmatrix{5\\ &5}^2.$$

Comment: Is it possible to find non nilpotent, non diagonal matrix?

Comment: Yes, see Lemma $2$ in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in Granville's paper [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi75LeGguX8AhUsiP0HHSDjDKQQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdms.umontreal.ca%2F%7Eandrew%2FPDF%2F4squares.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3J3h8TUfJDrXYTuJ2ndjxU), showing much more than just one example:

**Lemma 2:** Every matrix $M\in M_2(\Bbb Z)$ is expressible as the sum of three squares in $M_2(\Bbb Z)$.

We can choose $M=D^2$ with an arbitrary (non-nilpotent) $D$ and the follow the proof, i.e., taking
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \cr 0 & y\end{pmatrix},\; 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr z & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and an appropriate $C$. I suppose we can achieve that also $C$ is non-nilpotent.

Of course, if you only want one particular example, you can just take diagonal matrices with suitable entries.

Comment: ok thanks. Does similar result is for matrices with cubic powers? that is matrices with properties $A^3+B^3=C^3$

Comment: Yes, there are results, too. This is a good opportunity for you to have a look at the literature! It is easy to search in the web.

Comment: do you know any such link? please share

Comment: Did you ever try to search yourself? You really should try it. It is very important to know how to search. My first google hit is [this article](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj28OTFieX8AhVNgf0HHblYAO0QFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fjournals%2Fproc%2F2013-141-01%2FS0002-9939-2012-11297-3%2FS0002-9939-2012-11297-3.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0efkuGF2bLXdeX_vxsPGKM).

Comment: ok. Now I have understand how to search. tHANK YOU

Comment: You are welcome - very good!

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize the matrices satisfying $A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2$?